# Sorting partially sorted array

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

Suppose you are given a sorted list of n elements followed by f(n) randomly ordered elements. How would you sort the list if (i) f(n) = O(logn). I feel best algo would be merge sort but I am not sure of the resulting time complexity.

Comment: What do you mean by *list*? an array or a linked list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first sort the f(n) elements with any sort method and then use merge sort for the final phase. The time complexity would be **O(n)** as **O(log(n)<sup>2</sup>)** is negligible compared to the linear scan of the sorted portion.

If by *list* you mean an array, you could reduce the number of comparisons to **O(log(n)<sup>2</sup>)** by looking for the insertion point into the left portion using binary search. It would still take **O(n)** copying operations, so depending on the relative costs of copying vs: comparing, the time might stay sub-linear even for moderately large values of **n**.